# How to get coordinates of the selected item in a list view in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to get the coordinates (rectangle bounds: x, y, width and height) of the selected item in the listview relative to the screen (assume the listview fills the whole screen), so that I can create an object at that location and animate it to display some details of the selected item in my Xamarin.Forms app.

listview in xaml:

```
<ListView ItemTapped="ItemTapped"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="50">              
                <AbsoluteLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Info}"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5"/>
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

c# code for ItemTapped event:

```
void ItemTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var listView = (ListView)sender; // the listview
    var selectedItem = args.Item; // the selected item

    // need to get selected item coordinates for the animation
    var selectedItemBounds = ...

    ...
}
```

Eventually I want to create somehting like this in Xamarin.Forms with a listview (the number of objects in the listview varies):

[image: sample listview animation]

Comment: Cant you simply use [RowHeight](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.RowHeight/)? Is this what you're facing: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/64923#Comment_64923

Comment: If I use the `RowHeight` property, I also need to know the scroll position of the `ListView` so I can calculate the position of the selected cell (which I have no idea how to do it, since the scroll position is not a property of `ListView`)

Comment: GridView is not an option?

Comment: `GridView` can be used as a workaround, but it doesn't offer some `ListView` features such as grouping etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806805/xamarin-forms-how-to-expand-row-from-listview-over-full-screen-after-tap-or-cli

Comment: @GaurangDave this could work, but you need to reload the `ListView` 20+ times per second in order to perform the animation, which is not feasible for a huge `ListView`, since it will be very laggy.

Comment: You are going to have an extreme amount of trouble trying to work out the scroll position and the actual xy of an element in a listview and i don't think there is a reliable way. As for the wider problem of trying to animate the listview cell expanding, Maybe changing the cell template might be a simple hack. im not even really sure dynamically expanding a cell will give you smooth or consistent results. however id be keen to see an good answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick idea:

Have a view helper service which runs as a singleton:

```
interface IViewHelper
{
   Rect GetScreenCoordinates(View view);
}
```

Have a tap gesture added on the AbsoluteLayout you have in the ListView item template, and in the tap event handler call:

```
IViewHelper viewHelper = CrossViewHelper.Instance; 
Rect rcItem = viewHelper.GetScreenCoordinates((View)sender);
```

The native implementation of the service `GetScreenCoordinates` does two things:

```
// Get the native view from the Xamarin Forms view 
var nativeView = Platform.GetRenderer(view);

// Call native functions to get screen coordinates
Android: nativeView.GetLocationOnScreen(coords)
iOS: Use nativeView.ConvertPoint(coords, null)
```

See
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86941/get-x-y-co-ordinates-in-tap-gesture-inside-listview

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/PlatformRenderer.cs#L53

Also see: https://michaelridland.com/xamarin/creating-native-view-xamarin-forms-viewpage/

I don't have a complete code, but I hope this can help you.

I think in the end, after you implement animating and showing the view, you can refactor the implementation into a nice Behavior you can attach to any view, it won't matter if it's inside list-view or not, it will just work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it involves using custom renderer so it will be very tricky to implement.  I will play around with the implementation and see what I can get

Comment: This is very frustrating... What is the coords parameter?

Comment: how does your solution works? you cannot select 2 things. if you set InputTransparent on AbsoluteLayout, ListView will not be selected.

Answer (score 15):

I've created a dependency you can use to get the absolute position of a VisualElement in iOS and Android. I use it for a similar purpose. We use it to determine the position of a popup to show when tapping in the listview. Works perfectly:

Dependency:

```
public interface ILocationFetcher
{
    System.Drawing.PointF GetCoordinates(global::Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view);
}
```

iOS Implementation:

```
 class LocationFetcher : ILocationFetcher
 {
    public System.Drawing.PointF GetCoordinates(global::Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
    {
        var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(element);
        var nativeView = renderer.NativeView;
        var rect = nativeView.Superview.ConvertPointToView(nativeView.Frame.Location, null);
        return new System.Drawing.PointF((int)Math.Round(rect.X), (int)Math.Round(rect.Y));
    }
}
```

Android Implementation:

```
class LocationFetcher : ILocationFetcher
{
    public System.Drawing.PointF GetCoordinates(global::Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
    {
        var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(element);
        var nativeView = renderer.View;
        var location = new int[2];
        var density = nativeView.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

        nativeView.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
        return new System.Drawing.PointF(location[0] / density, location[1] / density);
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Emil we also have an UWP implementation:

```
public System.Drawing.PointF GetCoordinates(global::Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
{
    var renderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.GetRenderer(element);
    var nativeView = renderer.GetNativeElement();
    var element_Visual_Relative = nativeView.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
    Point point = element_Visual_Relative.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
    return new System.Drawing.PointF((int)Math.Round(point.X), (int)Math.Round(point.Y));
}
```

usage example:

```
var locationFetcher = DependencyService.Get<ILocationFetcher>();
var location = locationFetcher.GetCoordinates(myVisualElement);
```

Be sure to properly register the dependency correctly (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/ ) in the android and ios using the dependency attribute. Otherwise the DependencyService.Get will return null.

Comment: for your usage example `var location = locationFetcher.GetCoordinates(myVisualElement);`, how do you get the VisualElement of the cell in the listview?  I can only get the `Item` object and the `ListView` in the `ItemTapped()` event handler in my question.

Comment: Al cell itself is not a visual element. You need to pass the content (eg stacklayout) of a cell to the method

Comment: When I call `var locationFetcher = DependencyService.Get<ILocationFetcher>();`, `locationFetcher` is `null` (therefore calling`var location = locationFetcher.GetCoordinates(myVisualElement);` crashes the program).  Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Please take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction on how to configure and register a dependency

Comment: I've altered the answer to be more clear. If it works, don't forget to mark my answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: @xamDev89 we actually use it to determine the position of an element within a viewcell, and it works fine. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Good Job i can use your code and get the Points exactly... thanks

Comment: I spent last 3 days coming up with a function that would extract position of visible cells based on the amount of points that listview has scrolled, and then use the position to 'activate' the most visible item. And obviously due to some devices being slow and jittery in terms of scrolling compared to others, it was not always accurate. I kept banging my head for past few hours. Then I found your solution. And tested it. And it worked. And now I look at those three days and you know what I feel? [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-oP3KFe4ko)

Comment: great job. it worked and I used it for my share dialog.

Comment: like @Patrick asked how do you fetch the myVisualElement? in which action do you do that? can you clarify this?

Comment: @Emil like I answered patrick, the visual element is for instance a stacklayout within the listview item. I don't have any code at hand that uses this, but probably you can get this item by looking at the "sender" parameter of the itemtapped event handler of the listview. But this dependency is not limited to the listview control, it can get the coordinates of any xamarin.forms visualelement on the screen

Comment: thanks, i figured out later. your code perfectly works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You absolutely nailed it! :)

Answer (score 2):

PaulVrugt's answer perfectly works for IOS and Android. Just to extend his implementation for anyone requires also UWP.

```
  public System.Drawing.PointF GetCoordinates(global::Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element)
        {
            var renderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.GetRenderer(element);
            var nativeView = renderer.GetNativeElement();
            var element_Visual_Relative = nativeView.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
            Point point = element_Visual_Relative.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
            return new System.Drawing.PointF((int)Math.Round(point.X), (int)Math.Round(point.Y));
        }
```

Comment: Nice @Emil , I've included your code in my answer for completeness.

Comment: @Emil, Instead of "renderer.GetNativeElement()" which returns null always for me, I used "renderer.ContainerElement" which solved my issue in UWP. By the way, I am using CollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an `ILocationFetcher` implementation of the `GetCoordinates` method.

In my case, I needed to **get the bounds of the element relative to the parent element** (the child element is inside the parent element). If no parent element is specified, the method returns the bounds of the element relative to the window. Using the `inPixels` parameter, **you can request the dimensions in pixels** (may be required if you are drawing something using SkiaSharp).

**Dependency interface:**

```
public interface ILocationFetcher
{
    RectangleF GetCoordinates(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement parentElement, bool inPixels = false);
}
```

**Android Implementation:**

```
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(LocationFetcher))]
namespace App.Droid
{
    public class LocationFetcher : ILocationFetcher
    {
        public RectangleF GetCoordinates(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement parentElement, bool inPixels = false)
        {
            IVisualElementRenderer renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(element);
            Android.Views.View nativeView = renderer.View;
            float density = inPixels ? 1 : nativeView.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

            ViewGroup parentNativeView = null;
            if (parentElement != null)
            {
                parentNativeView = Platform.GetRenderer(parentElement).View as ViewGroup;
            }

            float x;
            float y;
            float width;
            float height;

            if (parentNativeView == null)
            {
                var windowBounds = new Android.Graphics.Rect();
                nativeView.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(windowBounds);
                int statusBarHeight = windowBounds.Top;

                var elementLocation = new int[2];
                nativeView.GetLocationInWindow(elementLocation);

                x = elementLocation[0] / density;
                y = (elementLocation[1] - statusBarHeight) / density;
                width = nativeView.Width / density;
                height = nativeView.Height / density;
            }
            else
            {
                var elementBounds = new Android.Graphics.Rect();
                nativeView.GetDrawingRect(elementBounds);
                parentNativeView.OffsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(nativeView, elementBounds);

                x = elementBounds.Left / density;
                y = elementBounds.Top / density;
                width = elementBounds.Width() / density;
                height = elementBounds.Height() / density;
            }

            return new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS Implementation:**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(LocationFetcher))]
namespace App.iOS
{
    public class LocationFetcher : ILocationFetcher
    {
        public RectangleF GetCoordinates(VisualElement element, VisualElement parentElement, bool inPixels = false)
        {
            IVisualElementRenderer renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(element);
            UIView elementNativeView = renderer.NativeView;
            nfloat scale = inPixels ? UIScreen.MainScreen.NativeScale : 1;
            UIView parentNativeView = null;
            if (parentElement != null)
                parentNativeView = Platform.GetRenderer(parentElement).NativeView;
            CGRect rect = elementNativeView.ConvertRectToView(elementNativeView.Frame, parentNativeView);
            float x = (float)Math.Round(rect.X * scale);
            float y = (float)Math.Round(rect.Y * scale);
            float width = (float)Math.Round(rect.Width * scale);
            float height = (float)Math.Round(rect.Height * scale);
            return new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```