# How to get tap coordinates from ItemTappedEventArgs

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, event-handling

I have a handler for a click on an item in a `ListView`. In the handler, how can I determine the coordinates of the tap location ?

The handler looks like this:

```
async void HandleItemTapped (object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item == null)
    return;

  // get tap position in sender
  Point tapPosition = ???

  ...
}
```

A position relative to `e.Item` would be fine, or relative to it's parent or even in screen coordinates.

Comment: XF doesn't expose this info to any ListView events

Comment: So, is there no way to get this info ? I need to get the tap location so I can display something in proximity.

Comment: Like [pan gesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pan)?

Comment: I don't know. Can that give me a click location in a list item ?

Comment: @PeriHartman To get selected item coordinates, you can take a look [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263876/how-to-get-coordinates-of-the-selected-item-in-a-list-view-in-xamarin-forms/51422564).

Comment: @Cherry Not at all. That gives the coordinates of the whole object. I'm looking for the coordinates of the click (or touch) point.

Comment: @PeriHartman Do you have any solution now?

Comment: @Cherry - No. I'm investigating other tools, particular SyncFusion and Uno.

Comment: @PeriHartman Yes, maybe it is another way to achieve your goal.